# A problem about Sindel sequences and the Prague clock

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Consider the following periodic Sindel sequence
\begin{equation}
1\:2\:3\:4\:3\:2\:\:\:1\:2\:3\:4\:3\:2\:\:\:1\:2\: 3\:4\:3\:2
\end{equation}

The period sequence $1\:2\:3\:4\:3\:2$ is a sequence of numbers whose sum is the modulus $m$ and the period length is the number of terms in this sequence ($6$ in this exemple).

A Sindel sequence has the following nice summation property: it is possible to insert, in the periodic sequence, commas (or any other symbols) and $+$ signs so that the « visible sums » separated by the commas form the sequence of all the positive integers in their normal order.
In our example, we have
\begin{equation}
1,\: 2,\: 3,\: 4,\: 3+2,\: 1+2+3,\: 4+3,\: 2+1+2+3,\: 4+3+2,\: 1+2+3+4,\:...
\end{equation}
For every modulus $m$, there is a Sindel sequence.
For example, for $m=17$, there is a Sindel sequence whose period sequence is $1\:1\:1\:1\:2\:4\:1\:4\:2$ and for $m=19$, the period sequence is $1\:1\:1\:3\:1\:2\:1\:5\:2\:2$.
There are nice arithmetic problems related to those sequences, most of them using triangular numbers.
A math professor asked the following:

Is it possible to choose a large enough $m$ in such a way that the number $2021$ appears in the corresponding Sindel sequence ?

Do you know if there is a way to find a solution using triangular numbers ?
Many Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/barbeau/vig13.pdf) is a good starting point for those who don't know these sequences.

Comment: With 2021 in the problem, and the style of presentation, this seems like it *might* come from a contest or similar (e.g. an application to special mathematics program). Can you provide the source of this problem to reassure readers that the contest/whatever is over if applicable?

Comment: Mark S. the problem just appeared in a discussion on a forum. The discussion was about the famous astronomic Prague clock and an article on the Mathematical Intelligencer from John Conway (and others) about the arithmetic of the Prague clock. I tried to solve the problem but I don’t understand why there is a 0 on the sequence.

Comment: I tried a lot of values for m (there is an algorithm) but none of the corresponding Sindel sequences had the sequence 2021. Perhaps I don’t understand the formulation of the problem. But this is not (as far as I know) an IMO problem.